# nested value from nested index python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, nested

I am trying to get an output list from nested list based on nested indices.

Input:

```
list_a = [(a,b,c,d), (f,g), (n,p,x)]

sub_index_a = [(0,2),(1),(0,1)]
```

Output:

```
output_list = [(a,c), (g), (n,p)]
```

Answer (score 0):

well having `("g")` just evaluates to `"g"`,the actual tuple of that would look like `("g",)` (`tuple(["g"])`), same as `(1)` but I think found a half-decent workaround? Hopefully, this is your desired solution.

```
list_a = [('a','b','c','d'), ('f','g'), ('n','p','x')]

sub_index_a = [(0,2),(1),(0,1)]

print([tuple([list_a[x][indx] for indx in i]) if type(i) in [tuple, list] else list_a[x][i] for x,i in enumerate(sub_index_a)])
```

```
[('a', 'c'), 'g', ('n', 'p')]
```

if you want everything returned as a tuple you can modify the comprehension to:

```
print([tuple([list_a[x][indx] for indx in i]) if type(i) in [tuple, list] else tuple([list_a[x][i]]) for x,i in enumerate(sub_index_a)])
```

```
[('a', 'c'), ('g',), ('n', 'p')]
```

note:

> if you want everything to be nested (with a single element) you would want a list of lists; E.g. `[[0,2],[1],[0,1]]`

Answer (score 0):

```
list_a = [('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('f', 'g'), ('n', 'p', 'x')]
sub_index_a = [(0, 2), (1,), (0, 1)]


def check(i, e):
    r = []
    for ee in e:
        r.append(list_a[i][ee])
    return tuple(r)


outputlist = [check(i, e) for i, e in enumerate(sub_index_a)]
print(outputlist)
```

This evaluates to

```
[('a', 'c'), ('g',), ('n', 'p')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` and a nested comprehension:

```
list_a = [("a","b","c","d"), ("f","g"), ("n","p","x")]
sub_index_a = [(0,2),(1,),(0,1)]  # note the comma in the second tuple

output_list = [tuple(sub[i] for i in i_s) for sub, i_s in zip(list_a, sub_index_a)]
# [('a', 'c'), ('g',), ('n', 'p')]
```